# Old html not replaced when using angular-animate

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular-animate, and encountered a problem:

with ng-repeat, ng-form and some validation such as required,
when scope objects change, old html are not replaced, but the same ones are copied and appended, as shown in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y0kq4hm68QPOeBvlWO01?p=preview)

html:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl as vm">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in vm.products" ng-form="form">
            <td>
                <input name="name" ng-model="p.productName" required/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="vm.change()">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

and script:

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', function() {
        this.change = function() {
            this.products = [
                {productName: '1'},
                {productName: '2'},
                {productName: '3'},
                {productName: '4'},
                {productName: '5'}
            ];
        };
        this.change();
    });
```

ng-repeat, ng-form, validation and scope objects are all required to reproduce this problem. If I replace 'products' with some primitive array, such as [1,2,3,4,5,6], the problem disappears.

Is there any solution, except removing angular-animate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
required=""
```

from the input, like so

```
 <input name="name" ng-model="p.productName" />
```

This isn't in a form (unless you are planning on it being in one) so you don't need `required`.

Comment: I need validation though... in my project, I use ui-validate to validate my inputs, and use form.inputName.$invalid(something like that). I found that any validation will cause this problem, so I just use required to show the case.

Comment: @shallweel then this is inside a form? Are you just trying to validate that someone has typed something in there? As mentioned, you didn't show or say this was a form, because if it's not you can do custom validation that isn't `required=""` .

Comment: yes, there is ng-form attribute with ng-repeat. I need form.inputName.$invalid and custom validation of ui-validate. I think it's a bug of angular-animate. I got rid of angular-animate at last...